# loop in python and converting strings

Tags: python

I'm new to programming and I'm having a hard time understanding how to ask the user if they want to run it again?

```
    def pigLatin(word):
     """
   Function that converts word into Pig Latin form
     """

  # Checking for starting letter as vowel
  if word[0] in ['a','e','i','o','u']:
   return word + "way"

  # Checking for vowel index
  for i in range(1, len(word)):
      # Checking for vowels(including y)
       if word[i] in ['a','e','i','o','u','y']:
       # Updating vowel index
       vowelIndex = i;
       break;

  # Forming pig lating word      
   return    word[vowelIndex:] + word[0:vowelIndex] + "ay";


 def removePunctuation(text):
  """
   Removes punctuation from text
  """

  # List of punctuation characters
  punctuations = ['(', ')', '?', ':', ';', ',', '.', '!', '/', '"', "'"]

   # Iterating over punctuations
   for ch in punctuations:
   # Replacing punctuations
   text = text.replace(ch, "")

   # Returning text
   return text


  def main():
  """
   Main function
   """
   # Reading line of text
   text = input("\n Enter a line of text: ")

   # Removing punctuation
   text = removePunctuation(text)

   # Converting to lower case
   text = text.lower()

 print("\n\n Pig Latin form: \n");

  # Iterating over words
  for word in text.split(" "):

   # Converting word to Pig Latin form
   word = pigLatin(word)

   # Printing word
   print(word, end = " ");

   print("\n");


  # Calling main function
  main()
```

How exactly would I add a loop that asks the user to continue or not? I'm new to programming and im very confused. I also don't understand how to add the English form of the sentence before the pig latin form??
can someone please help!

Comment: Please fix your indentation before we can have a look at your code!

Comment: Use a do-while, simple!

Comment: Welcome to SO. Unfortunately this isn't a discussion forum or tutorial. Please take the time to read [ask] and the links it contains.  Invest some time with [the Tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/index.html) practicing the examples. It will give you an idea of the tools Python offers to help you solve your problem.

Comment: how would i add that? could you show me @AakashVerma

Comment: ["Can Someone Help Me?" is not a valid SO question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question).  This usually suggests that what you need is half an hour with a local tutor or walk through a tutorial, rather than Stack Overflow.

Comment: Also, there are many such examples on line and on Stack Overflow.  Research first!

Comment: This question needs more help than we can provide. We like helping people, but sometimes you need to help yourself first by reading a book on the topic, the on-line documentation, or asking someone you know. Once you understand the topic a little better, we invite you to edit this question, fix the obvious mistakes, and get it re-opened.

Comment: The problems with this question are: 1. It's really two questions 2. Most of the code isn't relevant to either question - a minimal attempt at solving each issue in its own question would be better 3. The title doesn't really match what is being asked. I think closing it would be a little harsh, since the actual questions are pretty simple, but it could certainly do with improvement.

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution might look something like this:

```
while True:
    main()

    response = input("Continue?")
    if response != 'y':
        break
```

You'll probably want to be a little less strict about the inputs you accept.

I think it would be better practice to put this loop inside your main function (and have a check on `__name__` before invoking it), but this at least demonstrates what the loop would look like.

Answer (score 0):

you can use a `while` loop in your `main` and a string like -1 to exit

```
def main():
   while True: 
   """
   Main function
   """
   # Reading line of text
   text = input("\n Enter a line of text or -1 to exit: ")
   if text == '-1':
      exit(0)
   # Removing punctuation
   text = removePunctuation(text)

   # Converting to lower case
   text = text.lower()

 print("\n\n Pig Latin form: \n");

  # Iterating over words
  for word in text.split(" "):

   # Converting word to Pig Latin form
   word = pigLatin(word)

   # Printing word
   print(word, end = " ");

   print("\n");
```